# SI + Observer pattern

Tags: java, spring-integration

i have a codebase which uses spring-integration.

```
<integration-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                               channel="ftpChannel"
                               session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                               filter="myCustomFilter"                                                                                             
                               auto-create-local-directory="true"
                               delete-remote-files="false"                                                                    
                               remote-directory="/foo/bar"                                                                     
                               local-directory="file:output">
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>
</integration-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>



<integration:channel id="ftpChannel">
        <integration:queue />
</integration:channel>

<integration:service-activator id="mySA"  method="handleMessage" input-channel="ftpChannel" output-channel="outputChannel" ref="myDataGetter">
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>  
</integration:service-activator>
```

The bean for myCustomFilter is working fine and I am getting filtered files in handleMessage() method of myDataGetter bean.

So far so good.
Now in myDataGetter bean, I am further filtering files based on date e.g. the poller will get me 9 files, but actually they are 3 version for 3 dates only.

```
data_file1.20130816
data_file1.20130815
data_file1.20130814
data_file2.20130816
data_file2.20130815
data_file2.20130814
data_file3.20130816
data_file3.20130815
data_file3.20130814
```

Now my objective is to get latest 3 files i.e. 20130816 versions for data_file1,2 and 3.
So I got a logic build up in handleMessage method to construct the HashMap which would contain latest versions of these 3 files. It done with a naive logic of iterating over list of data and compare the file in subject with it. After few iteration, I get the HashMap build up which contains latest 3 files.

Now my next requirement is to pass these 3 files to next bean via a channel.

But the bean which should read data from the channel should only read when the HashMap is fully built with latest 3 data files.
Is there anything that can be done in SI so that data is put to next channel only after processing all incoming data and filtering out a set out of it?

I can think about having the myDataGetter been as obeservable and the bean for next channel as observer. But it does not fit into how things are done in SI.

Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `<aggregator/>` with a custom release-strategy.